# pyspark memory problems when using ".count()" on sort-of-big files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 1 spark master running with 3 slaves on separate machines (each machine with 50GB of memory) on different machines pointing to the master.

I open up pyspark with:

```
pyspark --master spark://mymastermachine:7077
```

I then run a command sc.textFile that reads in a file from hdfs that is 7GB in size. However, when store that into a variable "myfilerdd", then do a myfilerdd.count(), I see messages like this:

```
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on ######:##### in memory (size: 1473.0 B, free: 255.1 MB)
WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor 0 with no recent heartbeats: 160788 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost an executor 0 (already removed): Executor heartbeat timed out after 160788 ms
```

In my spark master url at port 8080, I see that the job has failed. One thing I notice is that under "Running Appications" I see:

```
Application ID  Name    Cores   Memory per Node Submitted Time  User    State   Duration
app-3535323432-0000 PySparkShell    32  512.0 MB    ##### ####  mbaker  RUNNING 4 s
```

Note the Memory per node is 512.0MB, is this the reason why my "myfilerdd.count()" is failing? Because the data exceeds 512MB? I do not get this same issue when I use the sc.textFile on a file that is small like 10MB.

When I attempt to run in local mode:

```
pyspark --master local[4]
```

Then do the same thing, the pyspark shell hangs on things like:

```
 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Removed broadcast_2_piece0 on ####### in memory (size: 1473.0 B, free: 255.1 MB)

- after waiting a long time, below shows - 

 Exception in thread "stdout writer for python2.7" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

My workers look beefy:

```
Worker Id   Address State   Cores   Memory
worker-457453474554 ipdaddress:#####    ALIVE   32 (32 Used)    50.0 GB (512.0 MB Used)
```

Am I not setting up my cluster correctly or am missing some configuration option?

Note: SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=10g and SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=10g in the spark-env.sh

Comment: Ok so why don't you increase the worker memory then?

Comment: yes. by default spark.executor.memory is 512m only. that is reflecting in your "My Workers look beefy".  change it to some ng,ex : 10g (10 gigs)

Comment: yes, I've set the SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=10g and SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY=10g in the spark-env.sh file, but it seems to have no effect. I know for sure its reading the spark-env.sh file since I do set SPARK_MASTER_PORT to something not default and it works. Is there some other configuration or am I not running my code correctly to take advantage of the cluster?

Comment: I've had this issue when the file I'm reading is corrupted. I doubt that's the case, but it's worth checking.

Comment: FIle does not appear to be corrupted... :( It is snappy compressed though.